# Subsample multi-sensor time series data using Python's panda.Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, sampling

I have a file coming from multiple sensor readings. Each line is of the following format:

```
timestamp sensor_name sensor_value
```

e.g.

```
191.12 temperature -5.19
191.17 pressure 20.05
191.18 pressure 20.04
191.23 pressure 20.07
191.23 temperature -5.17
191.31 temperature -5.09
...
```

The frequency of the readings is irregular, approximately 10-20Hz. I need do downsample these readings to 1Hz and output the result in the following format

```
timestamp sensor_1_value sensor_2_value ... sensor_n_value
```

reflecting the (running?) mean value of the sensor readings in the successive seconds, e.g.

```
timestamp temperature pressure
191.00 -5.02 21.93
192.00 -5.01 21.92
193.00 -5.01 21.91
...
```

I loaded each line of the input file into a dictionary as follows:

```py
   def add(self, timestamp, sensor_name, sensor_value):
     self.timeseries[sensor_name].append([timestamp, sensor_value])
```

... and created a DataFrame from the dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(self.timeseries)
```

... but I need some guidance how to move forward from here, i.e. what's an elegant way to perform the sampling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're doing but this is what I'd do to solve the problem. It assumes your data file is space-separated with a header row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep="\s", index_col=None)

# Take the mean of the values within a second
data = np.floor(data["timestamp"])
data = data.groupby(["timestamp", "sensor_name"]).mean()
data = data.reset_index()

# Pivot
data = data.pivot(index="timestamp", columns="sensor_name", values="sensor_value")
```

If you have some other concept for "downsampling" in mind for this context you should do that instead of mean.

Comment: Your post doesn't have anything new. Does this answer not do what you want? It takes a flat file and turns it into a dataframe which is `[Seconds x Sensors]` with mean values for each second.

Comment: Your code fails at `data = data.groupby(["timestamp", "sensor_name"]).mean()` with `KeyError: 'timestamp'`

Comment: Aight, you should either fix the column names to match your column names, or you should fix the `read_csv` function. I'm afraid that I can't help you with that as it appears that you haven't accurately shared the file data structure.